# Increment quantity but not more then main quantity field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table `proforma_invoice_items`

```
-----------------------------------------
    id  |   qty |   total_invoice_qty   |
-----------------------------------------
    452 |   50  |   45                  |
```

Now, i want to increment `total_invoice_qty` value with `10`, but not maximum `qty` value `50`

I have tried bellow query :

```
update proforma_invoice_items a set a.total_invoice_qty = a.total_invoice_qty+10 where a.id = 452 and a.total_invoice_qty < a.qty
```

and result is :

```
-----------------------------------------
    id  |   qty |   total_invoice_qty   |
-----------------------------------------
    452 |   50  |   55                  |
```

My expected result is maximum `qty` value `50` like

```
-----------------------------------------
    id  |   qty |   total_invoice_qty   |
-----------------------------------------
    452 |   50  |   50                  |
```

Comment: how 50 is coming in total_invoice_qty  column desired result.. should it be 45 i.e. no change in case of qty=50 ?

Comment: is total_invoice_qty  = 45 then auto increment 5 not 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`LEAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least):

> With two or more arguments, returns the smallest (minimum-valued)
>   argument.

```
UPDATE proforma_invoice_items a
SET a.total_invoice_qty = LEAST(a.total_invoice_qty + 10, a.qty)
WHERE a.id = 452
```

Comment: I put the link and the summary in the answer. In essence, what will happen is that your `total_invoice_qty` will be set to whichever is least of either `total_invoice_qty + 10` or `qty`

Comment: The link to the documentation is in my answer, my comment explains how it applies to your case. What more do you need?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE proforma_invoice_items 
SET total_invoice_qty  =  CASE WHEN total_invoice_qty  + 10 > qty THEN qty
                               ELSE  total_invoice_qty  + 10 END
WHERE id = 452
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully below query help you

```
update proforma_invoice_items a 
set a.total_invoice_qty = 
            a.total_invoice_qty + (Case WHEN a.qty - a.total_invoice_qty >= 0 THEN 10 ELSE a.qty - a.total_invoice_qty END)  where a.id = 452 and a.total_invoice_qty < a.qty
```

Comment: Sorry a.qty - a.total_invoice_qty >= 10

Answer (score 0):

A generic query cannot be hardcoded like WHERE id = 452, Try this

```
UPDATE proforma_invoice_items  
SET total_invoice_qty  = CASE
   WHEN  (total_invoice_qty+10) < 50 THEN total_invoice_qty+10
   ELSE 50
END
```

Comment: *"A generic query cannot be hardcoded"*, yet you're hard-coding 50.

Comment: id=452 will only work for 1 record. I don't think you need lessons on this. However that 50 is going to work on all record

Comment: No, I do not need lessons on this. There is however no reason to assume that OP wants to update all his records. And even if they did, instead of setting the value to either `total_invoice_qty + 10` or the value of the `qty` field, your query just sets it to 50 instead of the value of the `qty` field. That is not what was requested.

Answer (score -1):

```
update proforma_invoice_items a set a.total_invoice_qty = case when a.total_invoice_qty+10 < a.total_invoice_qty then a.total_invoice_qty+10 else a.total_invoice_qty end  where a.id = 452 and a.total_invoice_qty < a.qty
```

Try this